# Why does python use two underscores for certain things?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm fairly new to actual programming languages, and Python is my first one. I know my way around Linux a bit, enough to get a summer job with it (I'm still in high school), and on the job, I have a lot of free time which I'm using to learn Python.

One thing's been getting me though. What exactly is different in Python when you have expressions such as

```
x.__add__(y) <==> x+y
x.__getattribute__('foo') <==> x.foo
```

I know what methods do and stuff, and I get what they do, but my question is: How are those double underscore methods above different from their simpler looking equivalents?

P.S., I don't mind being lectured on programming history, in fact, I find it very useful to know :) If these are mainly historical aspects of Python, feel free to start rambling.

Comment: You can find some information here: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, power for the programmer is good, so there should be a way to customize behaviour. Like operator overloading (`__add__`, `__div__`, `__ge__`, ...), attribute access (`__getattribute__`, `__getattr__` (those two are differnt), `__delattr__`, ...) etc. In many cases, like operators, the usual syntax maps 1:1 to the respective method. In other cases, there is a special procedure which at some point involves calling the respective method - for example, `__getattr__` is only called if the object doesn't have the requested attribute and `__getattribute__` is not implemented or raised AttributeError. And some of them are really advanced topics that get you deeeeep into the object system's guts and are rarely needed. So no need to learn them all, just consult the reference when you need/want to know. Speaking of reference, [here it is](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

Comment: You're pretty good at explaining things, thanks! One question though, can you name a common case (perhaps a link to a code example) where these double underscore methods do something different than the operators?

Comment: Huh? The special methods that are operators are just called right away (afaik). Of course there are many others that don't represent operators, like the `__getattribute__` we both already named or `__enter__`/`__exit__` for with statements (`with open("file") as f: do_stuff(f)`). In these cases, there are some more complex rules, and the documentation knows them better than I.

Comment: I agree with S, the *actual* explanation comes only after quite a bit of rambling that only makes sense *after* you've read the linked bit.  That's why you go "Huh?" in your first comment.

Answer (score 31):

Here is the creator of Python [explaining it](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/adding-support-for-user-defined-classes.html):

> ... rather than devising a new syntax for
>   special kinds of class methods (such
>   as initializers and destructors), I
>   decided that these features could be
>   handled by simply requiring the user
>   to implement methods with special
>   names such as `__init__`, `__del__`, and
>   so forth. This naming convention was
>   taken from C where identifiers
>   starting with underscores are reserved
>   by the compiler and often have special
>   meaning (e.g., macros such as
>   `__FILE__` in the C preprocessor).

...

> I also used this technique to allow
>   user classes to redefine the behavior
>   of Python's operators. As previously
>   noted, Python is implemented in C and
>   uses tables of function pointers to
>   implement various capabilities of
>   built-in objects (e.g., “get
>   attribute”, “add” and “call”). To
>   allow these capabilities to be defined
>   in user-defined classes, I mapped the
>   various function pointers to special
>   method names such as `__getattr__`,
>   `__add__`, and `__call__`. There is a
>   direct correspondence between these
>   names and the tables of function
>   pointers one has to define when
>   implementing new Python objects in C.

Answer (score 16):

When you start a method with two underscores (and no trailing underscores), Python's [name mangling](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) rules are applied. This is a way to loosely simulate the `private` keyword from other OO languages such as C++ and Java. (Even so, the method is still technically not private in the way that Java and C++ methods are private, but it is "harder to get at" from outside the instance.)

Methods with two leading and two trailing underscores are considered to be "built-in" methods, that is, they're used by the interpreter and are generally the concrete implementations of overloaded operators or other built-in functionality.

Comment: That's good to know, but Python is my first programming language. I don't know what "private" is or name mangling, as delnan posted in a comment below. Thanks though, this answer will be much better for me once I do.

Comment: From what I hear, you don't typically use the `__` lead to do private, but rather you use it when your function might step on the namespace of another. With that in mind, I've seen people say to use a single underscore to mark it as an "implementation detail".

Answer (score 5):

They are used to specify that the Python interpreter should use them in specific situations.

E.g., the `__add__` function allows the `+` operator to work for custom classes. Otherwise you will get some sort of not defined error when attempting to add.

Comment: Nice and concise. Where else might they show up commonly in Python besides custom classes?

Answer (score 3):

From an historical perspective, leading underscores have often been used as a method for indicating to the programmer that the names are to be considered internal to the package/module/library that defines them.  In languages which do not provide good support for private namespaces, using underscores is a convention to emulate that.  In Python, when you define a method named '__foo__' the maintenance programmer knows from the name that something special is going on which is not happening with a method named 'foo'.  If Python had choosen to use 'add' as the internal method to overload '+', then you could never have a class with a method 'add' without causing much confusion.  The underscores serve as a cue that some magic will happen.

Answer (score 2):

A number of other questions are now marked as duplicates of this question, and at least two of them ask what either the `__spam__` methods are called, or what the convention is called, and none of the existing answers cover that, so:

There actually is no official name for either.

Many developers unofficially call them "dunder methods", for "Double UNDERscore".

Some people use the term "magic methods", but that's somewhat ambiguous between meaning dunder methods, special methods (see below), or something somewhere between the two.

---

There *is* an official term "special attributes", which overlaps closely but not completely with dunder methods. The [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) chapter in the reference never quite explains what a special attribute is, but the basic idea is that it's at least one of the following:

- An attribute that's provided by the interpreter itself or its builtin code, like `__name__` on a function.
- An attribute that's part of a protocol implemented by the interpreter itself, like `__add__` for the `+` operator, or `__getitem__` for indexing and slicing.
- An attribute that the interpreter is allowed to look up specially, by ignoring the instance and going right to the class, like `__add__` again.

Most special attributes are methods, but not all (e.g., `__name__` isn't). And most use the "dunder" convention, but not all (e.g., the `next` method on iterators in Python 2.x).

And meanwhile, most dunder methods are special attributes, but not all—in particular, it's not that uncommon for stdlib or external libraries to want to define their own protocols that work the same way, like the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) protocol.

Answer (score 0):

*[Speculation]* Python was influenced by [Algol68](http://algol68.sourceforge.net), [Guido](https://www.linkedin.com/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Fpython-history%2Eblogspot%2Ecom%2Eau%2F2009%2F04%2Forigins-of-pythons-functional-features%2Ehtml&urlhash=hkao&_t=tracking_disc) possibly used Algol68 at the [University of Amsterdam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Amsterdam) where Algol68 has a similar "[stropping regime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stropping_%28syntax%29#Examples_of_different_ALGOL_68_styles)" called "Quote stropping". In Algol68 the **operators, types and keywords** *can* appear in a different typeface (usually ****bold****, or *__underlined*__), in sourcecode files this typeface is achieved with quotes, e.g. 'abs' (quoting similar to quoting in '[wikitext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language#Text_formatting)')

### Algol68 ⇒ Python (Operators mapped to member functions)

- 'and' ⇒ __and__
- 'or' ⇒ __or__
- 'not' ⇒ not
- 'entier' ⇒ __trunc__
- 'shl' ⇒ __lshift__
- 'shr' ⇒ __rshift__
- 'upb' ⇒ __sizeof__
- 'long' ⇒ __long__
- 'int' ⇒ __int__
- 'real' ⇒ __float__
- 'format' ⇒ __format__
- 'repr' ⇒ __repr__
- 'abs' ⇒ __abs__
- 'minus' ⇒ __neg__
- 'minus' ⇒ __sub__
- 'plus' ⇒ __add__
- 'times' ⇒ __mul__
- 'mod' ⇒ __mod__
- 'div' ⇒ __truediv__
- 'over' ⇒ __div__
- 'up' ⇒ __pow__
- 'im' ⇒ imag
- 're' ⇒ real
- 'conj' ⇒ conjugate

In Algol68 these were refered to as **bold names**, e.g. **abs**, but "under-under-abs" __abs__ in python.

My 2 cents:  ¢ So sometimes — like a ghost — when you cut and paste python classes into a wiki you will magically reincarnate Algol68's **bold** keywords. ¢