# Variables of form __something__

Tags: python, variables

What is the purpose of python variables `__something__`
e.g. `__name__`, `__file__`

I often see them in real python programs.
Is there a list of these variables?

thank you

Comment: See this question & answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python

Comment: `__main__` doesn't belong there -- it's `if __name__ == '__main__':` so it's `__name__` that is special like `__file__` etc., not `__main__`.

Comment: Aren't they a naming convention for internal variables to python modules/libraries? Like _variableName in c#

Comment: Or this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443043/why-does-python-use-two-underscores-for-certain-things

Comment: @MikeCialowicz That definitely isn't the same question and I don't think the answers really address this at all.

Comment: @Oliver The conventions are for `_foo` or name mangling is `__foo`, `__foo__` is different.

Comment: @Farmer_Joe good link; this is an exact duplicate and that question's answers cover all the bases and have links to the relevant docs.

Comment: @agf sorry confused between Mike and Joe links

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) covers this:

> In addition, the following special forms using leading or trailing
>   underscores are recognized (these can generally be combined with any
>   case convention):
>
> - _single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator.  E.g.
>     "from M
>       import *" does not import objects whose name starts with an
>     underscore.
> - single_trailing_underscore_: used by convention to avoid
>     conflicts with
>       Python keyword, e.g.
>
>   Tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')
> - __double_leading_underscore: when naming a class attribute,
>     invokes name
>       mangling (inside class FooBar, __boo becomes *FooBar*_boo; see
>     below).
> - __double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__: "magic" objects or
>       attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces.  E.g.
>     __init__,
>       __import__ or __file__.  Never invent such names; only use them
>       as documented.

The final bullet point is pertinent.

> Is there a list of these variables?

I doubt that there is an official list of all such double leading and trailing underscore names, but I could not say so for sure.

Comment: They're mostly on the http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html page, either under "Special Method Names" or "The Standard Type Hierarchy" for `__file__` and `__name__` -- I don't see `__all__` anywhere on that page though.

Answer (score 1):

[Check this chapter of Python manual](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html). Does it satisfy you?

Comment: Please don't just provide a link, provide some context, and make the link test relevant like "Check out this chapter of the Python docs about the Python Data Model".

Answer (score 1):

They're considered special or magic.  The language doesn't prevent you from creating your own, but don't.

Here is a [good guide on the magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) but there are also special attributes, such as `__all__`, which is normally pronounced "dunder all" or "under under all".