# "This constructor takes no arguments" error in __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting an error while running the following code:

```
class Person:
  def _init_(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def hello(self):
    print 'Initialising the object with its name ', self.name

p = Person('Constructor')
p.hello()
```

The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "./class_init.py", line 11, in <module>  
    p = Person('Harry')  
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

What's the problem?

Comment: The answers have pointed out that `__init__` uses double underscores. But the reason you get the error message is that by default your class is supplied with an empty `__init__(self)` method inherited from `object`.  Since you did not override that method, it was the one that was called.

Comment: On similar case of typos (in this case a single underscore instead of two) I fell into the same mistake by naming the method `__ini__`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The method should be named `__init__` to be a constructor, not `_init_`. (Note the double underscores.)

If you use single underscores, you merely create a method named `_init_`, and get a default constructor, which takes no arguments.

Answer (score 11):

Use double underscores for `__init__`.

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name):
```

(All [special methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) in Python begin and end with double, not single, underscores.)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3443428/1322401) is how Python's use of double underscores came to be.

Answer (score 3):

You should use double underscores (`__init__`)(**Dunder or magic methods in python**) to declare python constructor.

**[Basic customization:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)**

`__init__` called after the instance has been create by `__new__` and use to customize the created object.

> Called after the instance has been created (by **new**()), but before it is returned to the caller. The arguments are those passed to the class constructor expression. If a base class has an **init**() method, the derived class’s **init**() method, if any, must explicitly call it to ensure proper initialization of the base class part of the instance; for example: super().**init**([args...]).

> Because **new**() and **init**() work together in constructing objects (**new**() to create it, and **init**() to customize it), no non-None value may be returned by **init**(); doing so will cause a TypeError to be raised at runtime.

We have two types of **Constructor** in python:

- **default constructor:** which is used when you don't declare the parameterized constructor. its definition has only one argument which is a reference to the instance being constructed (a.k.a `self`).

```py
def __init__(self):
    # default constructor
```

- **parameterized constructor:** which takes other parameters in addition to the `self` parameter.

```py
def __init__(self, parameters):
    # parameterized constructor
```

if you don't declare parameterized constructor, python uses the default constructor which doesn't take any parameter. So you passed an argument to default constructor and the exception has been thrown.

**How to fix it?**

Just declare a parameterized constructor by which you can instantiate your instances.

**Python3:**

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```